# Confusing trigonometry limit

Tags: limits, trigonometry

If $\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x-y)}{(x-y)} = 1$

then why is

$\lim \limits_{(x,y) \to (0,0)}\frac{\sin(x-cos(y))}{(x-cos(y))} = sin(1)$ ?

I would have thought the second one should be the same kind of notable limit as in the first case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply because $\;x-\cos y\xrightarrow[(x,y)\to(0,0)]{}0-1=-1\neq0\;$